# Añadir condición a un JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

tengo la siguiente base de datos

[image: Relacion]

Tabla Bill

[image: Bill]

Tabla Bill_Details

[image: Bill-Details]

Y Tabla Type

[image: Type]

Quiero mediante una query mostrar una columna como la siguiente:

[image: Need]

Considero que la siguiente query está bien realizada, sin embargo Access me dice que hay un conflicto con el `SELECT` que incluye una palabra reservada, le falta un argumento o está mal escrito, o bien los signos de puntuación no son los correctos.

```
SELECT

Bill.Id_Bill, 
600,
 "TOTAL", 
IIf(qul.DebSum<=qul.CreSum,qul.CreSum-qul.DebSum, ""), 
IIf(qul.DebSum>=qul.CreSum,qul.DebSum-qul.CreSum, ""), 
Bill.NIT, 
Bill.Date2, 
Bill.Comt

FROM Bill INNER JOIN (

SELECT 
Id_Bill, 
SUM(Deb) AS DebSum,  
SUM(Cre) AS CreSum,  

FROM Bill_Details 

GROUP BY Bill_Details.Id_Bill, Type.Id_Type)  AS qul ON Bill.Id_Bill = qul.id_Bill;
```

Estaría eternamente agradecido con alguna sugerencia para poder dar con mi error, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo dos fallos en tu consulta,hay que quitar una "," antes de un FROM, y añadir la tabla Type en el FROM Bill_Details. Para que tenga la funcionalidad como es descrito en la tabla iría así:

```
SELECT 
    Bill.Id_Bill,                                               
    Type.Id_Type,                                                  
    Type.Info,
    Bill_Details.Deb, 
    Bill_Details.Cre, 
    Bill.NIT,                                                     
    Bill.Date2,                                                     
    Bill.Comt
FROM 
    Type RIGHT JOIN (Bill INNER JOIN Bill_Details
        ON Bill.Id_Bill = Bill_Details.Id_Bill)
    ON Type.Id_Type = Bill_Details.Id_Type;

UNION

SELECT 
    Bill.Id_Bill,                                                        
    600,                                                             
    "TOTAL",
    IIF(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre) >= 0, ABS(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre)), Null ), 
    IIF(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre) <= 0, ABS(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre)), Null ),
    Bill.NIT,                                                     
    Bill.Date2,                                                     
    Bill.Comt

FROM Bill INNER JOIN Bill_Details
    ON Bill.Id_Bill = Bill_Details.Id_Bill

GROUP BY Bill.Id_Bill, Bill.NIT, Bill.Date2, Bill.Comt                     
ORDER BY Bill.Id_Bill;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, sin embargo no veo la necesidad de agrupar por `Type.Id_Type` la he ejecutado y me aparecen 12 registros mitad con Id_Bill 1 otra mitad con Id_Bill 2, y todos con TOTAL y 600, y no únicamente dos filas con esta información al final de cada Id_Bill

Comment: Mirando de nuevo la query, veo más o menos lo que buscas. Viendo el detalle de la imagen que pones como resultado,no entiendo bien cómo obtener las 2 líneas de 600 y TOTAL (desconozco Access). Yo he probado la siguiente query en Oracle y me muestra los otros registros:     SELECT
Bill.Id_Bill, 
Type.id_type,
IIf(qul.DebSum<=qul.CreSum,qul.CreSum-qul.DebSum, ""), 
IIf(qul.DebSum>=qul.CreSum,qul.DebSum-qul.CreSum, ""), 
Type.info, 
Bill.NIT, 
Bill.Date2, 
Bill.Comt

FROM Bill, Bill_Details, Type where Bill.id_Bill = Bill_Details.id_bill and Bill_Details.id_type = Type.id_type;

Comment: Gracias por la información, he editado la respuesta para mostrar la tabla en Access